# How to make a stay-open applescript for Photoshop CS6

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I'm working on a stay-open (on idle) applescript to watch a folder and process every incoming item. However, I'm not able to loop through the incoming files, if any. How to fix this?

```
on idle
    tell application "Finder"

        -- Folders
        set InFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Nick:Documents:Applescript:Beeld bewerken:In:"
        set OutFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Nick:Documents:Applescript:Beeld bewerken:Out:"

        set MyFiles to (every file in folder ((InFolder) as text))
        set MyFiles to MyFiles as list

        set NumberOfFiles to (number of files in folder ((InFolder) as text))

    end tell

    if NumberOfFiles > 0 then
        repeat with i in MyFiles
            tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"

                open (item i of MyFiles)

                -- Edit item

            end tell
        end repeat
    end if
    return 10
end idle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be using folder actions rather than an on idle handler. Attach this folder action to your target folder.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving droppedItems
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6" to open anItem
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```